# How to check, if link is about to open in new or current tab

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

I have service worker, that listens all fetch events.

Is there any way to check, if request started by user who clicks on link, is about to open in current, or new tab?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(async function respond() {
        if (linkAboutToOpenInCurrentTab) {
            // do something
            return fetch(newRequest)
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
    }());
});
```

Comment: I think it depends on the kind of service worker and the API you are subscribed to. In the case of chrome extensions you should access the `chrome.history`, also don't forget to add permissions in manifest for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Workers only respond to network requests (the `FetchEvent`), and all user interactivity and DOM events are not accessible to Service Workers.

You could attempt to capture link clicks from the application itself (outside the SW).  `target` would be "_blank" for new tabs/windows.

```
<a id="a1" href="">Self</a> - 
<a id="a2" target="_blank" href="">New Tab/Window</a>

<script>
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for (const link of links) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const target = this.target;
      console.log(target)
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yea, I did something similiar. Intercepting all clicks on document.links, then preventdefault and fetch with custom header. And then service worker check if request has that header. It works, but I wanted pure service worker solution... but its impossible. Anyway thanks :)